# Does WSO2 Identity Server support a predefined list of options for user claim values

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using the latest version of WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0. I'm adding some custom claims to the user profile. Is there a way to provide such fields for a claims value that represents select menu with options, where the user could able to choose only one of predefined set of options?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you meant, But this blog post [1] may help you. it would be great, if you could provide more details.

[1] http://pathberiya.blogspot.com/2012/05/claim-management-with-wso2-identity.html

Comment: Hi Asela! Do you see the dropdown "Profile configuration". I need a way to create a claim which values could be limited only to a predefined set of options, just like the dropdown for "Profile configuration". That's it.